# Find tuple in list of tuples in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuple (simulationtime,efficiency) and I want to find the tuple in which the maximum efficiency is stated with respect to the minimum simulation time. Any hints on how that could be done?
A small part of the otherwise very large list:

> [(109.00537427472713, 0.8), (109.00588429136333, 0.85), (109.00649436705454, 0.86), (110.00055419961151, 0.86), (110.00122432147343, 0.86), (110.00172424060818, 0.86), (110.00236418239592, 0.86), (110.00292411815163, 0.86)]

I want the output to be (109.00649436705454, 0.86) from the list since it corresponds to  max efficiency at min simulation time. Right now I am doing:

```
next(v for v in AoD_log if v[1] >= 0.85)
```

but the maximum achievable efficiency: index[1] of the tuple is not always known.

Comment: Please post some example data and your attempt at a solution.

Comment: @kindall, I have updated the question

Comment: @ManlaiA it is the minimum simulation time which has the maximum possible efficiency : 0.86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
your_list = [(109.00537427472713, 0.8), (109.00588429136333, 0.85), (109.00649436705454, 0.86), (110.00055419961151, 0.86), (110.00122432147343, 0.86), (110.00172424060818, 0.86), (110.00236418239592, 0.86), (110.00292411815163, 0.86)]
max_efficiency = max(your_list, key=lambda x : x[1])[1]
min_simulation_time = min((x for x in your_list if x[1]==max_efficiency))
```

Output:

```
(109.00649436705454, 0.86)
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off of @Manlai A’s answer:

Try this:

```
next(v for v in AoD_log if v[1] == max(AoD_log, key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

Comment: what I did was `min(i for i in AoD_log if i[1]==max(AoD_log)[1])` and it seems to do the job, I am still a beginner at python so I do not understand how this implementation differs from the one above.

Comment: Yeah that works, the log sample you gave looks to be sorted by simulation time, though - eliminating the need for the min check